# Python to loop through pandas dataframe, insert different recipients, title and email contents into outlook email

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, email, outlook

I have a dataframe (df) with the values of each column listed as per below:

[Example of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDlAM.png)

How do I loop through the pandas dataframe based on unique values in df['Owning'] and df['Type'] and seperate it to different Outlook e-mails with different Owner and CC list?

Below is the code to send for one 'Owning' type.

```
TROGY=df[df['Owning']=='TROGY']

TROGY_21=TROGY[[TROGY['Type']=='210s']

TROGY_22=TROGY[[TROGY['Type']=='220s']

TROGY_21C2=TROGY_21[TROGY_21['CLASS']=='CLASS 2']

TROGY_21C3=TROGY_21[TROGY_21['CLASS']=='CLASS 3']

TROGY_22C2=TROGY_22[TROGY_22['CLASS']=='CLASS 2']

TROGY_22C3=TROGY_22[TROGY_22['CLASS']=='CLASS 3']



sender = 'donotreply@outlook.com'

recipient = TROGY['Owner'] ---- group by df['Owning'] and df['Type'] 

subject = 'Highlight For the Day XXX, YYYYY'



XXX referring to df['Owning']

YYYYY referring to df['Type'] 



msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

msg['Subject'] = subject

msg['From'] = sender

msg['To'] = ','.join(recipient)


body = ("""\

<html>

  <head></head><h2 align=center>CONVERSION</h2>

  <body>

         <div>Dear Conversion Owners, below is the highlight for the day.</div>

  Class 2

    {0}

  Class 3

    {1}

  </body>

</html>


""".format(TROGY_21C2_Block.to_html(),TROGY_21C3.to_html()))


msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('relay.xx.com', 'xx')

   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string()) 
        
   print ("Successfully sent emai")

   smtpObj.quit()

except smtplib.SMTPException:

   print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

Desired outcome will be total 5 emails be send out to the designated recipients stated in 'Owner' column with different email title.

Email 1 Title: 'Highlight For the Day TROGY, 210s'

Recipient: Kent, lili

Email 2 Title: 'Highlight For the Day TROGY, 220s'

Recipient: Kent,

Email 3 Title: 'Highlight For the Day PHM, 210s'

Recipient: bose

Email 4 Title: 'Highlight For the Day FUSION, 210s'

Recipient: Nikki

Email 5 Title: 'Highlight For the Day FUSION, 220s'

Recipient: gaddam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) with `["Owning", "Type"]` as arguments. After that, use `to_list()` over `g["Owner"]` to create the list of recipients. For the subject text you can use the return of the `groupby` function which is the name of the groups for each column used.

Input **sample.csv**

```
ID,Owning,CLASS,Type,Owner,CC list
GD8235,TROGY,CLASS 2,210s,Kent,John
GD8298,TROGY,CLASS 3,210s,Lili,Ricky
GD8238,PHM,CLASS 3,210s,Bose,Ricky
GD8239,FUSION,CLASS 3,220s,Gaddam,Edmund
GD8240,TROGY,CLASS 2,220s,Kent,John
GD8243,FUSION,CLASS 2,210s,Nikki,John
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
print(df)

groups = df.groupby(["Owning", "Type"])
for n, g in groups:
    recipient = ", ".join(g["Owner"].to_list())
    subject = f'Highlight For the Day {n[0]}, {n[1]}'

    print(f"Title: {subject}")
    print(f"Recipient: {recipient}")
```

```
Title: Highlight For the Day FUSION, 210s
Recipient: Nikki
Title: Highlight For the Day FUSION, 220s
Recipient: Gaddam
Title: Highlight For the Day PHM, 210s
Recipient: Bose
Title: Highlight For the Day TROGY, 210s
Recipient: Kent, Lili
Title: Highlight For the Day TROGY, 220s
Recipient: Kent
```